# how to get default selected printer's port name in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I wrote code to get name of printer which is installed in my system.but i don't know to get that printers port name. here the code what i wrote.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        PrintServer server = new PrintServer();

        foreach (PrintQueue queue in server.GetPrintQueues())
        {
            cboPrinters.Items.Add(queue.FullName);
        }

        var DefaultPrinter = new LocalPrintServer().DefaultPrintQueue;
        string default_name=DefaultPrinter.FullName;

        txxt_default.Text = "The default printe is "+" "+default_name;
    }
```

it's result will be like this

[image: printer]

[image]

i have to get selected printer's port name "DOP7"(mentioned below figure).please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [PrintQueue.QueuePort Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.queueport.aspx)?

```
string default_port = DefaultPrinter.QueuePort.Name;
```

**Update:**

Then I recommend adding `PrintQueue` object to `ComboBox`

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   PrintServer server = new PrintServer();

   foreach (PrintQueue queue in server.GetPrintQueues())
   {
      cboPrinters.Items.Add(queue);
   }
}
```

and using `DisplayMemberPath` for showing the `FullName`:

```
<ComboBox Name="cboPrinters"
          DisplayMemberPath="FullName"
          SelectionChanged="cboPrinters_SelectionChanged" />
```

In EventHandler you can get port name like this:

```
private void cboPrinters_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   PrintQueue printer = cboPrinters.SelectedItem as PrintQueue;
   string portname = printer.QueuePort.Name;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. i got what i need.but i need to get the select item's(from combobox items) queuepot name.i mean if i select Fax from combobox, i have to get that select items queueport name.pleae help me.

Comment: and then another thing is, i have to get the selected item's BAUD RATE,DATA BITS,PARITY,STOP BITS,PORT and FLOW CONTROL.pleae LPL help i fully hope you...

Comment: Please see my edit. For getting the [SerialPort Class Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport_properties) from a `QueuePort` please ask a seperate question.

Comment: above all are very useful to me but i have to get the selected item's BAUD RATE,DATA BITS,PARITY,STOP BITS,PORT and FLOW CONTROL.what should i do for that.please help me LPL.